# Command Prompt making a Username and Password

Tags: command-line, batch-file, syntax-error, command-prompt

i have tried this, but it keeps returning an error saying `the syntax of the command is incorrect`. Here is the code i tried:

```
@echo off
echo Enter Username and Password to view files

set /p user=Enter UserId:
set /p pass=Enter Password:

if /i %user%==admin (if /i %pass%==*my password was here*)

(goto admin1)

:admin1
..etc..
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is your use of parenthesis. Here's a re-done version of the same code.

```
@echo off
echo Enter Username and Password to view files

set /p user=Enter UserID: 
set /p pass=Enter Password: 

if /i %user%==admin (
    if /i %pass%==password goto admin1
)

:admin1
::More here...
```

Also, there is one thing wrong with this code (and yours, if it worked). No matter what user or password you put in, it would always go to `:admin1`. This is because batch files read from top to bottom, so it would skip the code within the `if` block and go to the `:admin1` block.

You can combat this by putting code in between the code that will redirect the user.

Also, I suggest you look at the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to format your question correctly (putting code in code blocks, links, etc).

Comment: Note that it would also work just as well without the parenthesis (E.g `if /i %user%==admin if /i %pass%==password goto admin1`, although it will render your script messy and hard to read.

Comment: thanks, i know how code is read i didnt put the whole thing here but i do have a "in case you were wrong" section. ill try this, oh and i have never used this site before and i actually didnt even think i would get an answer but ill format better next time.

Comment: i think the parenthesis give some seperation and wether or not they are needed they neat. and  i like being able to go back and read the code i write and alloy others to be able to do the same but thanks prof pickle! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your parenthesis are off.

```
@echo off
echo Enter Username and Password to view files

set /p user=Enter UserId:
set /p pass=Enter Password:

if /i "%user%"=="admin" (if /i "%pass%"=="password" goto admin1)

goto skip

:admin1
echo Done
goto END

:skip

:END
```

Comment: oh well that isnt the entirety of my code there is a skip of sorts and if you enter the wrong thing it sends you too the "you have entered incorrect info" then exit part of my code. but after i input the user and password it says synta error it doesnt continue